# Create Items that have same type/class as existing Wolfram Class

Tags: entity

I'm working on a food log using Wolfram Language and I've got a conundrum.

I would like to use the repository's existing `Food` entities, but there are items that I need to include that Wolfram does *not* have in its current `Food` repository.

So question is—how would I be able to create an item of the same `Food` type/class so that I can include it in my data?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2661817).